# How many bits should I use for bearer tokens?

Tags: hmac

I'm in the process of developing a service that can be accessed with bearer tokens. Currently I'm using a random UUID converted into a URL safe format. That is 128 bits. Users will be authenticated through a custom oauth2 server, client services (e.g. when the API is called on behalf of the client app) are going to login with HMAC-SHA digest auth.

Some questions:

- Is it enough to use HMAC-SHA256? Or should I use HMAC-SHA512 or maybe even SHA-3 for a brand new project? I don't think that the extra overhead would be a problem, but I'm not sure that it would provide significantly more security. I know that it is a bit opinion based, but still.
- What should be the length of the client secret for my HMAC algorithm? I'm not sure if it should be equal to the output block size, or the internal state size, or the input block size? (E.g. for SHA256, input block size is 512 bits, output block size is 256 bits.)
- Should I increase the number of bits in the bearer tokens too? I'm not sure that using SHA256 or SHA512 makes sense when the bearer token only has 128 bits.

Maybe using 160 token with HMAC-SHA1? I do not exactly see how the number of bits in hmac and/or bearer tokens affect security, or of it worth increasing one without the other.

**UPDATE** - although not stricly related to the question, I have changed the code to use SecureRandom instead of UUID:

```
public class UrlSafeTokenGenerator {
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int BITS = 128;
    private static final int BYTES = BITS/8;

  /**
   * Generates a new URL safe token.
   *
   * @return the newly generated token.
   */
  public String generate() {
    byte[] buff = new byte[BYTES];
    random.nextBytes(buff);
    String generatedToken = BaseEncoding.base64Url().encode(buff);
    return trimRight(generatedToken, '=');
  }

  /**
   * Trim returns string with all leading and trailing Unicode code points contained in cutset removed.
   */
  private String trimRight(String text, char cutset) {
    int i = text.length() - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && cutset == text.charAt(i)) {
      i--;
    }
    return text.substring(0, i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: 128 bits is enough, but in most languages UUIDs are not guaranteed to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: I was using java's uuid4. Can you suggest something for java? Possibly https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html ?

Comment: Java is one of the few languages where this is guaranteed safe: [docs for `UUID.randomUUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()): "The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.